# Broken VBA Control Logic

Tags: vba, logic

I have a VBA module that looks at Access controls and only selects controls that are acTextBox or acCheckBox. However, i am encountering an logic glitch in my If statement that should only allow acTextBox=109 and acCheckBox=106 controls through, but it is now letting a label through with a control value of 100 as you see in the immediate window. Whats going on?Im stumped.. It works if i remove the "or acCheckBox", but allows labels through when i include it, even though a label is not a checkbox.

This is a problem cause it gives me an error later on.

Cheers

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blCkM.png)

```
 For Each ctl In frm.Controls   Debug.Print ctl.Name
    With ctl
    Debug.Print ctl.ControlType
    'Avoid labels and other controls with Value property.
    If .ControlType = acTextBox Or acCheckBox Then
      If .Value <> .OldValue Then
```

Comment: `acTextBox Or acCheckBox` is equivalent to `109 Or 106` which is equivalent to `111`.  If you include your code in the question, we could show you how to fix it by copy/pasting your code, and editing it, but I'm certainly not going to type your code from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your Line

```
If .ControlType = acTextBox OR acCheckBox Then
```

with this

```
If (.ControlType = acTextBox) OR (.ControlType = acCheckBox) Then
```

Comment: You're kind - When they just give pictures of code in the question I usually insist that they replace it with the actual code before I give them working code. :D  (Pictures are hard for search engines to index, which makes for a very poor question.)

Comment: Verified. Also, uploaded code for indexing purposes. Love this community.  @YowE3K

Comment: I hadn't seen the consequences of using pictures. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The search engine reason is probably a minor point.  The major issue is that people often want to test that they can reproduce the OP's original problem using the original code, and that the problem is fixed using the edited code that they intend to include in the answer.  That is really hard to do if people just paste a screenshot of the code.  (And, to be honest, there is extra work involved in posting a screenshot into the question than simply copy/pasting code - so I can't understand why people do it.)